# Emacs `haskell-compile` for unit tests

Tags: haskell, emacs

Emacs newbie here, transitioning from Neovim.
I have a project in Haskell, and I am aware that I can run `haskell-compile` and it will execute `cabal build`. 2 questions please:

1. What can I do if I need `cabal test`?
2. What can I do if I need `cabal run`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future googlers, here is the solution I adopted:

```lisp
  (general-nmap haskell-mode-map
    "<leader>b" '(lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (save-some-buffers t)
                  (setq-local haskell-compile-cabal-build-command "cabal build")
                  (haskell-compile)))

  (general-nmap haskell-mode-map
    "<leader>t" '(lambda ()
                  (interactive)
                  (save-some-buffers t)
                  (setq-local haskell-compile-cabal-build-command "cabal test")
                  (haskell-compile)))
```